# what is the escape character in ant regular expression (regexp element) pattern

Tags: regex, string, ant, scripting

I am having a text file(f.txt), its content should be list of files(.c files, and other files) one by one, like below.

```
    first.c
    temp.c
    temp.txt
    a.txt
    second.c
    third.c
```

In this file i want to add some prefix and suffix to only `.c` files. for this purpose I have written the below ant script.

```
    <replaceregexp byline="true" file="f.txt">
        <regexp pattern="(.+).c"/>
        <substitution expression="PRE \1.c POST"/>
    </replaceregexp>
```

Its not working for the string `second.c`

Expected output is

```
    PRE first.c POST
    PRE temp.c POST
    temp.txt
    a.txt
    PRE second.c POST
    PRE third.c POST
```

Actual output is

```
    PRE first.c POST
    PRE temp.c POST
    temp.txt
    a.txt
    PRE s.c POSTond
    PRE third.c POST
```

Its treating `.` in `.c` as any character. But i kept it to parse exactly `.c`. I tried by using `\` before `.c` also like `<regexp pattern="(.+)\.c">`. But this also not helpful.

Please provide me a solution to get the expected output.

Note : I am using ant 1.7.0 in windows xp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to escape the `.` and probably use some kind of anchors, like:

```
<regexp pattern="^(.+)\.c$"/>
```

`^` and `$` meaning beginning and end of line. Without them lines like `foo.coo.txt` would match.

Comment: +1. Yes, the anchors and the backslash should have been there all along, but it seems to me it still should have worked correctly on `second.c`.  What am I missing?

Comment: @AlanMoore, good point. I don't know Ant, so can only speculate that some non-greedy-quantifiers setting is active.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to escape twice, like:

```
<regexp pattern="(.+)\\.c">
```

Comment: No, this is an XML attribute value, not a Java string literal.